# Good algorithm/technique to find overlapping values from objects' properties?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am making a timetabling application. The important classes are:

```
Period
    id: int
    clazz: Clazz  
SubjectTeacher
    subject: String
    teacher: String
    clazz: Clazz
    AllocablePeriods: List<Period>
```

Here is example data, where Jane and John teach at one class, and Jane in another class.

```
{sub435, Jane-Algebra-Class1, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}
{sub124, Jane-Calculus-Class2, {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}}
{sub875, John-English-Class1, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}} //he cannot take #8
```

---

My objective is to detect **possible swaps** for each `SubjectTeacher`. For example, in the above example, `Jane-Algebra-Class1` and `John-English-Class1` have potential swaps

```
{1,Jane-Algebra-Class1,John-English-Class1}
{2,Jane-Algebra-Class1,John-English-Class1}
...
{7,Jane-Algebra-Class1,John-English-Class1}
```

What is a good algorithm/technique to detect all possible swaps for all `SubjectTeacher`s?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but I think it is mainly because I don't understand the teaching system you imply. Are you asking for all pairs of numbers in the `AllocablePeriods` that are the same among different teachers?

Comment: It might sound trivial (without providing exact algorithm). Iterate subjects and use Set for detecting overlaps (e.g. method `retainAll`). Was'nt it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that the number of `AllocablePeriods` is relatively small. Then what you can do is iterate over all teachers, iterate over all their periods and add each such period to a Map mapping a period identifier to the teachers that can teach during this period:

```
Map<Integer, List<String> > periodTeachersMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
for (Teacher teacher: teachers) {
   for (AllocablePeriod period: teacher.getPeriods()) {
       if (periodTeachersMap.get(period.getId()) == null) {
           periodTeachersMap.put(period.getId(), new ArrayList<String>());
       }
       periodTeachersMap.get(period.getId()).add(teacher.getName());
   }
}
```

After this cycle you will have in `periodTeachersMap` for every period all the teachers that can teach in it. If you want the pairs themselves you can easily construct them from the List. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) approach in 6 (active) lines.