# Are "swap move factories" worth the effort?

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I noticed that for problems such as Cloudbalancing, move factories exist to generate moves and swaps. A **"move move"** transfers a cloud process from one computer to another. A **"swap move"** swaps any two processes from their respective computers.

I am developing a timetabling application.

1. A `subjectTeacherHour` (a combination of subject and teacher) have
   **only a subset** of `Period`s to which they may be assigned. If Jane teaches 6 hours at a class, there are 6 `subjectTeacherHour`s each which have to be allocated a `Period`, from a possible 30 `Period`s of that class ;unlike the cloudbalance example, where a process can move to any computer.
2. Only one `subjectTeacherHour` may be allocated a `Period` (naturally).

It tries to place `subjectTeacherHour` to eligible `Periods` , till an optimal combination is found.

---

### Pros

[The manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta1/drools-planner-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e3928) seems to recommend it.

> ...However, as the traveling tournament example proves, if you can remove
>   a hard constraint by using a certain set of big moves, you can win
>   performance and scalability...
>
> ...The `[version with big moves] evaluates a lot less unfeasible
>   solutions, which enables it to outperform and outscale the simple
>   version....
>
> ...It's generally a good idea to use several selectors, mixing fine
>   grained moves and course grained moves:...

While only one `subjectTeacher` may be allocated to `Period`, the solver must temporarily break such a constraint to discover that swapping two certain `Period` allocations lead to  a better solution. A swap move "removes this brick wall" between those two states.

So a swap move can help lead to **better solutions much faster**.

### Cons

A `subjectTeacher` have **only a subset** of `Period`s to which they may be assigned. So finding intersecting (common) hours between any two `subjectTeacher`s is **a bit tough** (but doable in an elegant way: [Good algorithm/technique to find overlapping values from objects' properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172690/good-algorithm-technique-to-find-overlapping-values-from-objects-properties) ) .

Will it only give me only small gains in time and optimality?

I am also worried about **crazy interactions** having **two kinds** of moves may cause, leading to getting stuck at a bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap moves are crucial.

Consider 2 courses assigned to a room which is fully booked. Without swapping, it would have to break a hard constraint to move 1 course to a conflicted room and chose that move as the step (which is unlikely).

You can use the build-in generic swap MoveFactory. If you write your own, you can say the swap move isDoable() false when your moving either sides to an ineligible period.

Comment: I take it (from your silence) that having two different kinds of moves dont ever cause the solver to get stuck at some place.

Comment: No. Either you decide that ineligible periods are a build-in hard constraints (and your Move.isDoable() assure that). Or ineligible periods are just normal hard constraints. See section "tips and tricks" of scoring in the manual.

Comment: It was never about unmovable planning entities, I try not to create undoable moves. It was about having two different kinds of moves acting on same problem state, it went against my common sense.  But thanks for remembering :D